# how to avoid SKNode's blink when i remove a moving node?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working with a little game,and my node is move like this:

```
    SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveToY:HEIGHT + self.frame.size.height / 2 duration:actualDuration];
[self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove, loseAction]] withKey:@"start"];
```

and i dissmiss it from another view, it just called this:

```
- (void)dissmissBubbleWithType:(BubbleType)type{
__block BOOL isDismiss = NO;
NSString *name = [[ResManager sharedManager] nameFromBubbleType:type];
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:name usingBlock:^(SKNode * _Nonnull node, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    BubbleNode *bubbleNode = (BubbleNode *)node;
    isDismiss = YES;
    [bubbleNode cracked];
}];
if (isDismiss) {
    [self.bubbleDelegate dismissBubbleWithType:type];
}
```

}

when I dissmiss a type, I use enumerateChildNodesWithName usingBlock
to remove my nodes;

And this is bubbleNode cracked,i use it to play a gif and remove it;

```
- (void)cracked{
self.name = @"cracked";
[self removeAllActions];
SKAction * actionMoveDone = [SKAction animateWithTextures:[ResManager sharedManager].bubbleCrackArray timePerFrame:0.2];
SKAction *done = [SKAction removeFromParent];
[self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMoveDone,done]]];
```

}

Now the problem is when I called dissmissBubbleWithType, nodes blink to an older position.
I think the reason is that when I called dissmissBubbleWithType and enumerateChildNodesWithName:name, the position.y of node is 100, but at the time that it removing, the position.y is 90(because it was moving).
I tried some way, such as
1.removeAllActions then play gif
2.removeFromParent without play gif
3.use foreach in scene.children
but it still blink

so pease help me out, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it.
I put enumerateChildNodesWithName into a sub thread, and put [bubbleNode cracked] into main thread.
so this enum will not influence node's move.